# Google Cloud bucket permission issue

Tags: wordpress, google-app-engine, bucket

I have deploy wordpress multiple site on google app engine and now i want to change uploads folder as google bucket folder where i can upload media. Now the following issue i have ..

Unable to create directory https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/media-wordpress/. Is its parent directory writable by the server?
  OR 
Unable to create directory gs://media-wordpress/. Is its parent directory writable by the server?

So how I can make writable for my wordpress site or ananamous users.

Sam

Comment: In this github issue https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/issues/518 it is suggested to use this https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-stateless/

Please read the issue and try the workaround. Let us know how it goes

Comment: If you are using App Engine Standard, there are two ways of achieving user uploads. Read [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/googlestorage/#Writing_files_from_your_app) and [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/googlestorage/user_upload)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create the bucket media-wordpress from your Developer Console or the gsutil tool for example as explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/creating-buckets). Once done, you'll be able to reference this bucket in Wordpress with the format https://storage.googleapis.com/media-wordpress/

Comment: already created the bucket and change the path in upload but getting error as describe in question ..please check below again...its parent directory writable by the server? OR Unable to create directory gs://media-wordpress/. Is its parent directory writable by the server?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Exactly:

```
Unable to create directory 1. Is its parent directory writable by the server?
```

on image upload. After two days of debugging I dumped exception:

```
Cannot use ACL API to set object policy when object policies are disabled
```

found [this advice](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/not-uploading-to-google-bucket/) and changed my bucket policy to "individual object permissions" aka "object-level permissions" on Permissions tab.